# How to wait until a Batch file operation has completed before redirecting its entire output to a text file?

Tags: batch

It is easy enough to redirect output to a text file with a `>`. For example:

```
for /l %%n in (1,1,10000) do (echo %%n>>output.txt)
```

Ot alternatively:

```
for /l %%n in (1,1,10000) do (call:sub %%n)
exit
    
:sub
    (echo %1)>>output.txt
exit /b
```

Either of which will create a text file listing the numbers 1 to 10,000.

However, these examples will write each line of output to the disk individually, and I do not like the thought of 10,000 individual writes to my SSD each time these Batch files are run.

So, Is there anyway that I could somehow instead queue an operation's generated output up in memory while it is in progress, and then have the entire output be written to disk in one write at the end?
Some advanced redirection trick?
Or maybe some way to store ongoing output in a variable, to be redirected later with echo `%output%>>output.txt`?

**Note**: The above are just examples, there is no need to suggest alternative methods for creating numbered lists! My query is general and about redirecting output to a text file while avoiding line-by-line disk writes.

Comment: A good OS should buffer these writes.

Answer (score 1):

> So, Is there anyway that I could somehow instead queue an operation's generated output up in memory while it is in progress, and then have the entire output be written to disk in one write at the end? Some advanced redirection trick? Or maybe some way to store ongoing output in a variable, to be redirected later with echo %output%>>output.txt?

Yes, definitely. Use powershell.

The beauty of powershell is that you can dump everything in a variable, array or dictionary, and then at the end, in a single write, write it entirely to disk.

Here's an example:

myscript.ps1:

```
# create the output variable that we'll write to disk later.
$output = @()

1..10000|foreach-object {
    #get the number: (this line is optional, but just to make it easier to understand)
    $number = $_

    #add the number to the output
    $output += $number
}


#print the output to the screen:
$output

#write the output to a file:

$output|out-file -FilePath "output.txt"
```

You can of course substitute the entire number thing. All you need to know is this:

```
# create the variable:
$output = @() 

# Add to it
$output += "something"

# Write it to disk:
$output|out-file -FilePath "output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```bash
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

>.\log.txt =;(
     for /l %%L in (1,1,10000)do echo/%%~L
    );=
```

> ***Note:** The above are just examples, there is no need to suggest alternative methods for creating numbered lists! My query is general and about redirecting output to a text file while avoiding line-by-line disk writes.*

```bash
 >redirect_file (
      use command blocks
    )
```

---

To redirect your results entirely from the execution of your bat, you can also execute it and redirect this execution to a final file, where a first call checks whether a file was passed, if not, the bat makes a second call to itself running and this time redirecting its result to a file, like this:

---

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions

rem :: checks if the variable has received value :: 
if /i "!_log!/" == "/" (

   echo/Batch call started: !date! - / - !time!

   rem :: If it has not received any value, it will assign and call the bat itself 
   set "_log="%temp%\log_bat.log"" && echo/>!_log! & "%~0" >>!_log! & exit /b

   rem :: As soon as it has received some value, the bat will continue executing, already saving in: !_log!
   
   ) else endlocal

:: your current code in bat starts at that point saving the outputs in "%temp%\log_bat.log” ::

...
```

---

Comment: Your question is generic, and so is the answer, but your observations are specific, for something more specific I suggest posting your code.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately neither of the first two worked for me. If I swap in a      "timeout /nobreak 60" command into your codes then still each second of the countdown gets written to the text file individually. Rather than the text file being created with all output all at once, after the timeout has completed. So still getting the multi-disk writes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The *`timeout.exe`* output contains a line break and backspace (character) , in that order per second, so this behavior is to be expected even when using redirection, and these characters are responsible for writing and rewriting on the same line.